# Required fields are not working with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have created a Registration Form and set its `input` field to `require` attribute but its not working with ajax

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input required  type="text" id="First_name" placeholder="Enter your First Name" value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input required  type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input required  type="text" id="reg_username" placeholder="Enter your User Name    " value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input required  type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input required  type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-lock login-field-icon"></i>
</div>
<a id="register" class="btn btn-success modal-login-btn">Sign up</button>
```

and here is ajax code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#register").click(function(e){         
   if($("form").valid()){
      e.preventDefault();
   }
  var firstname=$('#First_name').val();
  var lastname=$('#last_name').val();
  var username=$('#reg_username').val();
  var password=$('#password').val();
  var email=$('#email').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "doRegister.php",
    data: 
         "first_name=" +firstname+ "&last_name=" +lastname+ "&username="+ username+ "&password="+ password+ "&email="+ email ,
    success: function(html){
      document.write(html);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
});
</script>
```

i just want to run required field validation with ajax i could not find any solution .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use `submit` event instead of `click` in order to work the html5 validation. Submit event only fire after successfully validated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#register").submit(function(e) {
    //---------------^---------------
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstname = $('#First_name').val(),
      lastname = $('#last_name').val(),
      username = $('#reg_username').val(),
      password = $('#password').val(),
      email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "doRegister.php",
      data: "first_name=" + firstname + "&last_name=" + lastname + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&email=" + email,
      success: function(html) {
        console.log(html);
      }
    });
    return false;

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="register" role="form">
  <!---                       ---^----             ------>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required type="text" id="First_name" placeholder="Enter your First Name" value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required type="text" id="reg_username" placeholder="Enter your User Name    " value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value="" class="form-control login-field">
    <i class="fa fa-lock login-field-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success modal-login-btn">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i have updated code please ans according that. that code in not working

Comment: I still see this trying (snacksnippets block cross domain ajax requests) to submit even when a required field is not entered.

Comment: Still does the same thing though - watch your console when you click "Sign up" with an empty form

Comment: now required field is working but ajax is not fetching data from `doRegister.php` ???

Comment: @BilalMaqsood check your network tab in browser for ajax request

Answer (score 2):

If your form is invalid, you need to return out the function - `e.preventDefault()` is not enough to stop your ajax being executed

```
if($("form").valid()){
  e.preventDefault();
  return; // <-- here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those whose added the submit event but form is still submitting with page refresh even you added preventDefault();

Remeber if you are submitting the form through submit button and change the click event to submit like below

```
<button id="saveBtn" >Save</button>

$('#saveBtn').on('submit', function( e ) {
});
```

This is not going to work, why?
Becuase you change the event from click to submit but your form will be submitted with refresh.
How to fix this issue.

You need to call the form id in the submit event instead of submit button

```
<form id="form">
</form>

$('#form').on('submit', function( e ) {
});
```