# Required attribute and submit form button

Tags: php, ajax, email, attributes, required

This is my code:

index.php

```
<form action="">
<input placeholder="Name" class="form" id="nome" type="text" required/>
<input placeholder="Mail" class="form" id="mail" type="email" required />
<input placeholder="Object" class="form" id="oggetto" type="text" required />
<textarea placeholder="Message" id="text" class="form"></textarea>
<input class="formBtn" type="submit" id="submit"/>
<input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
```

script in index.php

```
    <script>
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var nameform = $('#name').val();
        var mailform = $('#mail').val();
        var objectform = $('#object').val();
        var textform = $('#text').val();
        var mailcomplete = 'Name='+nameform+'&Mail='+mailform+'&Object='+objectform+
'&Message='+textform;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'php/mail.php',
            data: mailcomplete,
            success: function() {
            alert("Well Done!");
            }

        });
});
```

mail.php

```
    <?php

$name = $_POST['Name'];
$mail = $_POST['Mail'];
$object = $_POST['Object'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];

mail("mail@mail.it", $object, $message,
     "From: $mail\r\n" .
     "Reply-To: $mail\r\n" .
     "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

?>
```

With this code I can send mail if all fields are null too.
I would add a control to send mail when all fields respect required attributes.
Tnk you so much! Bye

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Required fields are not working with ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876238/required-fields-are-not-working-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen because when submit button is clicked the ajax call is made to prevent such - make use of submit event regarding form in jquery, you can do as your wish with following code.

First add id to the form  like below:

```
<form action="" id="formId">
   <input placeholder="Name" name="Name" class="form" id="name" type="text" required/>
   <input placeholder="Mail" name="Mail" class="form" id="mail" type="email" required />
   <input placeholder="Object" name="Object" class="form" id="oggetto" type="text" required />
   <textarea placeholder="Message" name="Message" id="text" class="form"></textarea>
   <input class="formBtn" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit"/>
   <input class="formBtn" name="reset" type="reset" />
 </form>
```

Now for jquery code

```
 $(document).on('submit','#formId',function(e){
     // this will prevent form to submit
     e.preventDefault();
     // data need to send can be get with javascript serialize()
     var data = $("#formId").serialize();
     // now go for ajax call
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'php/mail.php',
        data: data,
        success: function() {
        alert("Mail inviata correttamente!");
        }

    });
 })
```

Comment: let me know whether it works for you or not... if worked please accept as correct answer

Comment: Sorry but this code don't work. I don't send mail... Tnk

Comment: Sorry there was a spelling mistake to function name .... in serialize() please try once again

Comment: oh we didnot provide any name to the form fields we need to do that ... so again i changed my answer please try once again.... Sorry, i could not figure out that mistake